# ASP .NET Code analysis tool to check cross site scripting

Tags: asp.net, code-analysis

I am aware of a tool which MS has provided which tells you about coss site scripting attack etc.
The tool is http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0178e2ef-9da8-445e-9348-c93f24cc9f9d&displaylang=en

But are there tools which you have used for ASP .NET applications which do similar to this and which one is widely used in ASP .Net applications ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately [CAT.NET is as good as dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891408/whats-the-status-of-cat-net) so you can rule that one out.

In terms of XSS detection, if you're wanting to test vulnerabilities in an existing app you need not constrain yourself to static code analysis or .NET specific tools. There are plenty of language agnostic scanners out there you can run against the URL of an existing site.

One I've found very useful in the past is [Netsparker from Mavituna Security](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/). This is really easy to get up and running with (download it, enter a URL in a nice UI, run the scan) and the results are easily interpretable. You can grab a free community version which will identify persistent and reflective XSS (among other vulnerabilities) or pay for a licensed edition with a heap of additional features.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Not really. Web protection library will protect my application. But how do I check an existing .Net application if it has flaws.